# How to make an absolute positioned circle responsive? Or other routes?

Tags: html, css, responsiveness

So my question is how do i make my CSS circle that is absolute positioned responsive? The circle (.full-circle)is positioned over my nav buttons, that spin when hovered. Here is my code, I'm using ASP.NET MVC.

HTML ----------

```
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            @*@Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })*@
        </div>
        <div class="full-circle"></div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "Index", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Work", "Work", "Home")</li>
            </ul>
            @*@Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")*@
            </div>
```

CSS----------

```
.full-circle {
 background-color: rgba(204, 0, 102, 0);
 border: 3px solid white;
 height: 120px;
 width: 120px;
 -moz-border-radius:75px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 75px;
 position:absolute;
 margin-left:22em;
 top:0px;
}
.navbar-nav li {
width:200px;
height:50px;
text-align:center;
padding:0 0 0 0;
}
.navbar .navbar-nav {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
}
```

Comment: change it to `position:relative`.... and then `margin : 0 auto`?? Another question , do you want to center it or something??

Comment: Well my next idea is to just use media queries and re position it alot as the screen shrinks. I was hoping to somehow incorporate some bootstrap in the nav to make it easier though.

Comment: I will give that a try dvenkatsagar

Comment: @BrandonCemprola My previous comment, will allow you keep the circle relative to the menu and centered in the middle. https://jsfiddle.net/54keabuz/

Comment: Yes sorry i should've mentioned that. My nav is centered on my page

Comment: So you want the circle to be on top of the menu or bottom??

Comment: The nav buttons are actually within the circle. I was trying not to change much with the <ul> but im thinking i'll have to.

Comment: I was able to get it working dvenkatsagar. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
use this..........

<style>
.full-circle {
 background-color: rgba(204, 0, 102, 0);
 border: 3px solid white;
 height: 120px;
 width: 120px;
 -moz-border-radius:50%;
 -webkit-border-radius:50%;
 position:absolute;
 left:0px;
 margin:0px;
}

</style>
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation of how this code solves the question. This will help the OP learn from your answer as well as help future searchers.